# Case insensitive index in Neo4j using Py2neo

Tags: indexing, neo4j, case-insensitive, py2neo

I want to make a case-insensitive index in Neo4j using Py2neo.
Read through the docs and googled a lot but didn't find anything. There seems to be this option in Java but not in Py2neo.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass configuration options into the `GraphDatabaseService.get_or_create_index` function as indicated here:

http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.get_or_create_index

These arguments are passed directly into the REST call as described here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-create-node-index-with-configuration

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When using [legacy indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) you can supply a configuration upon initial creation of the index. You have to set `to_lower_case=true` in combination with `type=fulltext`.

Schema indexes on the other hand do not yet support case insensitivity. As a workaround, introduce a copy of the respective property, e.g. name -> nameLower, which gets populated by the lowercase variant of that string. You could do something like this on existing datasets:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(nameLower);
// --- use seperate transaction 
MATCH (p:Person) set p.nameLower = lower(p.name); // maybe apply LIMITs for large amount of nodes
```

Your query string of course needs to use lower case:

```
MATCH (p:Person {nameLower:'john'}) RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using legacy indexing with the inbuilt batch functions of py2neo (get_or_create_index, add_indexed_node). Any idea how might I be able to include `to_lower_case=true` and `type=fulltext`? I also realize that making case-insensitive index using Cypher might be possible but I'd favor using the in built functions.